# Histogram drawing - Image processing tools

Tags: java, javascript, python, image-processing, histogram

I've an issue with drawing an image `histogram`. I would like to create simple image `histogram` with basic `adjustments`. The problem is if there are `simple` libraries/sdk that could help achieve this. The `technology` does not matter. I've found that `matlab` has a lot of image/graph processing tools but it is still kid of "inaccessible" due to the tools. Java/Javascript/python/c# would be great so that I've tagged this question.

AFAIK we can take as eg. `RGB` components to draw histograms and there would be great if those library would allow to `adjust` them and in response `process` the `image`. I think what I'm looking for is often used in every tool working with graphics.

thx

Answer (score 0):

For python you have matplotlib (http://matplotlib.org/index.html) , it's quite easy and very similar to matlab